# Can I use Windows 7 or Windows Professional on my T5600 chip

Tags: windows-7, memory, sony-vaio

I have a Sony Vaio that I haven't used for a few years, but is perfectly lovely and I would like to start re-using it.  It currently runs Vista and I would like to upgrade to Windows 7.  According to the computer screen, I understand it has an [Intel Core2duo T5600](http://ark.intel.com/products/27254/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-T5600-2M-Cache-1_83-GHz-667-MHz-FSB) chip, runs at 1.83GHz, has 2GB of RAM and an Nvidia GeForce Go 7400 graphics card.

Can I use Windows 7 professional or should I use Windows 7 32bit?
Would it operate Microsoft 2010 apps?

I tend to use my much faster and higher spec'd laptop - but the desktop VAIO is a really great machine and I want to be able to use both.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser, Can you clarify your question as professional comes in both 32 bit or 64 bit versions, Have you checked the min specs for the software you want to run?

Comment: any computer that could run windows Vista should be able to run windows 7 or windows 8 perfectly

Comment: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/upgrade-advisor

Comment: That laptop should be able to run both 32bit and 64bit versions of windows. With 2GB of RAM you are at the doubt point between 32 bit (uses slightly less RAM) and the 64 bit version. I would choose the 64 bit version just to keep things such as drivers the same for all devices. As to MS app: Why wouldn't it run them?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can run any of those options should work, or any of the options below.

- Windows 7 32bit
- Windows 7 64bit
- Windows Professional
- Windows Vista 32/64bit
- Even Windows 8 should run.

Since the computer only has 2GB of RAM I would probably recommend Windows 7, it won't really matter if you do 32bit or 64bit.  I would look into upgrading the RAM if possible, the processor should be okay for basic computing though.

Yes it should operate Office 2010 apps, it won't be screaming fast of course but it will work.

Comment: I would go for x86, the difference in performance with only 2GB of RAM is certainly worth it, unless the user plans to go above 4GB of RAM at some point.

Comment: Just to clarify.  AthomSfere said x86, that simply means 32bit.  I would probably have to agree with him.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can upgrade.

Official min requirements for Windows 7 from [windows.microsoft.com](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/system-requirements):

If you want to run Windows 7 on your PC, here's what it takes:

> •  1 gigahertz (GHz) or faster 32-bit (x86) or 64-bit (x64) processor
>
> •  1 gigabyte (GB) RAM (32-bit) or 2 GB RAM (64-bit)
>
> •  16 GB available hard disk space (32-bit) or 20 GB (64-bit)
>
> •  DirectX 9 graphics device with WDDM 1.0 or higher driver